# Array Index out of bounds exception error for java list

Tags: java, arrays, exception, arraylist, protocol-buffers

I am trying to put a 2d array in a 2d list. I am building a google protobuf. I cant figure out why I am throwing an exception. I have tried multiple suggestions on here on stack and none have been able to help.

here is my client side code :

```
public class google_cl extends Thread {


 static Array createArray() throws IOException{

     Array.Builder array = Array.newBuilder();

    double[][]arrays = new double[15][15000];

        for(int i=1; i< 15; i++){
            for(int j=1; j<15000;j++){
            arrays[i][j]=Math.random()*100; 
            }
        }
        for(int i=1;i<15;i++){
            for(int j=1;j<15000;j++){
                  array = Array.newBuilder().setArrays(i, arrays[1][j]);    
            }

            }
        //System.out.println(array);

        // Make connection and initialize streams
        Socket socket;
        try {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 9898);
             OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();


                ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);



        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return null;     

}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


Average.Builder avger = Average.newBuilder();

//avger.mergeFrom();

try{
    avger.mergeFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));


}
 catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(args[0] + ": File not found.  Creating a new file.");
    }

    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);// This is where              my error occurs.
    avger.build().writeTo(output);
    output.close();
}

}
```

Here is my server code:

```
public class google_sr {


static void average(Average average){



List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

list = Array.newBuilder().getArraysList();

double max = 0.00;
Double sum = 0.00;

  if(!list.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i =1; i<15000;i++) {

        sum += list.get(i);
    }
   max= sum.doubleValue() / list.size();
  }

  Average.Builder avg = Average.newBuilder();
  System.out.println(avg.setAverages((int)max));

}


 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

google_sr p = new google_sr();
     Average averag = Average.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));//Where my error occurs
     average(averag);
        if (args.length != 1) {

          System.err.println("Usage Error");
          System.exit(-1);
        }

 }
  }
```

Finally, here is my proto file:

```
message Array{
repeated double arrays = 1;
}

message Array2{

repeated Array arrays=1;

}

message Average{
optional int32 averages =1;

}
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at cisc_434_google_protocol.google_cl.main(google_cl.java:82)
```

Comment: post your stacktrace

Comment: post the console output so that the question is clear

Comment: Just did, @SanjaySinghRawat

Comment: Looks like the try has an uncaught index out of bounds exception, which is why the error is after it. A good habit I developed is putting an if check on the args length before doing anything with the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing fileName in args[0] as parameter. You have checks at wrong place : After creating file, you are checking with args.length. Change the order of your code statements so that args.length was checked first and then create file.

Try this code.

```
if ( args.length != 1){
    System.out.println("Exiting program. Usage: java google_cl fileName");
    System.exit(-1);
}
google_sr p = new google_sr();
Average averag = Average.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
average(averag);
```

1. If you are using command line to run the program, call the program as

   **java google_cl someFileName**

   Or
2. **If you are using IDE like eclipse, Right Click on the java class Name -> Click on Run As -> Run Configuration -> Arguments -> Program Arugments**. Add fileName in program arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>       at cisc_434_google_protocol.google_cl.main(google_cl.java:82)

means that at line 82 of your class, you are trying to access the first item of an array but the array is empty.

If this is line 82:

```
Average averag = Average.parseFrom(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

it means that `args` is empty. In other words you are not passing any arguments to your program.

Comment: just to add to your answer, these arguments need to be specified at command line. If you are using any IDE such as eclipse, check out- https://www.cs.colostate.edu/helpdocs/cmd.pdf

Comment: exactly.. as @CrakC mentioned.. you have to pass command line argument because it seems you are trying to get command line data but not passing it.